# Multivariable Product Rule, Integration by Parts, Derivative, etc.

Tags: reference-request, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am searching for a book on multi-variable calculus that explains multi-variable product, multi-variable integration by parts, etc.

As an example, here's a simple problem that I would like to be able to do after reading this book.

Let u(x) = || x - y ||^2 + 3x^t z.  Find the derivative of u with respect to x.

Can anyone recommend a book to me?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The free book [Vector Calculus](http://www.mecmath.net/) by Corral covers enough of differentiation for your immediate needs. Multivariable integral identities are covered more thoroughly in *Vector Calculus* by Marsden and Tromba. Or you can dive right into [Zorich](http://books.google.com/books/about/Mathematical_Analysis_I.html?id=qA5FTMT7HE4C).

Answer (score 0):

Introduction to Electrodynamics  by Griffiths has exactly the material that I was looking for, and it is explained well.